# Efficient way of getting list of EntityModel (Java, DXA 2.0)

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, java

We have a page that queries entities with certain criteria.

The way we implement it is by getting list of entity IDs, loop the IDs retrieve the entity model per ID and add it into the list.

Pseudo code:

```
Query query = new Query(...);
// Get list of ids from query
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList(query.executeQuery());

final WebComponentMetaFactory cmf = new WebComponentMetaFactoryImpl(brokerQuery.getPublicationId());

// Get component meta
List<ComponentMeta> componentMetas = ids.stream().map(cmf::getMeta)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Get entity model per component and add it to the list
componentMetas.forEach(meta -> {
   EntityModel entityModel = contentProvider.getEntityModel(meta.getId() + templateId, webRequestContext.getLocalization())
   list.add(entityModel)
});
```

This works, however from performance point of view is very slow because it needs to call `contentProvider.getEntityModel(...)` for every ID.

Is there a better solution for this? Perhaps an API from DXA that generates list of EntityModel?

Comment: which version of sites?

Comment: We use Tridion 8.5. I thought that won't matter much, because this is DXA framework related?

Comment: I just asked if it's  Sites 9.0+ graphql query it's possible to fetch the DCPs jsons using item query filter by a single call to fetch the items and also entity jsons data in the same response.

Comment: why you want this entity model list in a web application?

Comment: @Velmurugan With GraphQL, you could indeed retrieve DCPs with a single call.

But I wonder, if we could retrieve with DXA in a similar way (so you't have to deserilaize json to strongly typed object).

e.g. a method like 'contentprovider.getAllEntityModels(List of ID's).

I havn't seen a method like this in DXA 2.2 (java) version.

Comment: AFAIK, In DXA there is no getEntityModels API to fetch multiple DCPs by one call. alternatively, you can use the CIL library to fetch all the DCPs Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.ComponentPresentationFactory to  FindAllComponentPresentations

Comment: I know its only pseudo code but why do you need to fetch ComponentMeta?

Comment: @Neil It's not the case anymore in our code base. It does look redundant if I give the example a 2nd look

Comment: I don't think its possible to achieve what you want in 8.5. The DXA Model Service can only return a single model per call I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Use this below CIL API to Fetch multiple DCP content by a single call example provided below is based on .NET similar API also available in java.

```
string[] componentUris = query.ExecuteQuery();

var components = componentUris
                .Select(componentUri => { TcmUri uri = new TcmUri(componentUri); return (ComponentPresentation)new ComponentPresentationFactory(uri.PublicationId).FindAllComponentPresentations(componentUri)[0]; })
                .Where(cp => cp != null)
                .Select(cp => cp.Content)
                .ToList();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is that really a single call though? Aren't you just calling FindAllComponentPresentations() for each item in the componetUris array?

Comment: @Velmurugan In one of the comments you mentioned graphql. Now we are trying to migrate to 9.5 site and wonder if you have sample code for graphql?